# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : read xml read outerxml remove tags

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, xmldocument, asp.net-core-6.0

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app, and I have to read an XML with this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<taglines common-copyright="©2007 ">
    <tagline brandID="1" brandName="BCBS" >
        <registered registered="®Registered">
        </registered>
        <copyright copyright="©2007">
        </copyright>
        <tagline2 tagline2="Data.">
        </tagline2>
    </tagline>
</taglines>
```

I need to read the content in tag `tagline2`

The way I am doing it is

```
private  string ReadXMLAnthemFile()
{
    string footer = "";

    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.Load(String.Concat(this.Environment.WebRootPath,"/img/TagLines.xml"));

    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDocument.SelectNodes("taglines/tagline/tagline2"))
    {
        footer = node.OuterXml;
    }

    return footer;
}
```

But `node.OuterXml` returns the entire tag

```
<tagline2 tagline2="Data."></tagline2>
```

How can I get only the data inside the tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to read the "outer" XML - you need to reach into the XML node you've fetched, and read it's `tagline2` attribute - if present.

Try something like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDocument.SelectNodes("taglines/tagline/tagline2"))
{
    if (node.Attributes["@tagline2"] != null)
    {
        footer = node.Attributes["@tagline2"].Value;
    }
}
```

That should get you the `.Value` of the `tagline2` attribute of the XML node that your XPath expression matches - the value would be `Data.` in your case here.